# Get HangoutLink after api update

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

This is how I retrieve data from google-calendar-api:
I Recently added `conferenceDataVersion=1`, but didn't make a difference.

```js
const uri = `${googleapiURL}/calendar/v3/calendars/${calendarId}/events?conferenceDataVersion=1`;

const response = await rp.post({
  uri,
  headers: {
    authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
  body,
  json: true,
  simple: false,
  resolveWithFullResponse: true,
});
```

I used to be able to get the hangout as following:

```
const link = response.body.hangoutLink,
```

But now we don't have `hangoutLink` attribute inside body anymore. How could I get it?

I was reading [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) about body request query parameters. There is a `conferenceData` but there is no example of how to use it.

Comment: When the event gets inserted, can you try viewing it on your Google Calendar web UI & check if you see the Google Meet option on the event like [this sample image](https://imgur.com/a/wWimioC)?

Comment: @IrvinJayG.Hi! Thanks for your help, dude. The meet wasn't created, I didn't have the "join" button as your image shows. The official documentation is a little confusing but I found out that I needed to add  `conferenceData` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After September 2020. Google Calendar API changed and meets are no longer created as default. We need to explicit "tell" we want to create a meet (the hangout link).

1 - First, we need to add a **query parameter** `conferenceDataVersion=1`

2 - We need to **add a new object to the request body**.

```
conferenceData: {
  createRequest: {
    conferenceSolutionKey: {
      type: 'hangoutsMeet',
    },
    requestId: <<randomString>>,
  },
}
```

#### More Information:

As per the documention for [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) and the [Event resource reperesentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource):

> **`conferenceDataVersion`:** `integer`
>
> > Version number of conference data supported by the API client. Version 0 assumes no conference data support and ignores conference data in the event's body. Version 1 enables support for copying of ConferenceData as well as for creating new conferences using the createRequest field of conferenceData. The default is 0. Acceptable values are `0` to `1`, inclusive.
>
> ---
>
> **`conferenceData.createRequest`:** `nested object`
>
> > A request to generate a new conference and attach it to the event. The data is generated asynchronously. To see whether the data is present check the `status` field.
> >
> > Either `conferenceSolution` and at least one `entryPoint`, or `createRequest` is required.
>
> ---
>
> **`conferenceData.createRequest.conferenceSolutionKey.type`:** `string`
>
> > The conference solution type.
> >
> > If a client encounters an unfamiliar or empty type, it should still be able to display the entry points. However, it should disallow modifications.
> >
> > The possible values are:
> >
> > - "`eventHangout`" for Hangouts for consumers (http://hangouts.google.com) // DEPRECATED
> > - "`eventNamedHangout`" for classic Hangouts for G Suite users (http://hangouts.google.com) // DEPRECATED
> > - "`hangoutsMeet`" for Google Meet (http://meet.google.com)
> > - "`addOn`" for 3P conference providers
>
> ---
>
> **`conferenceData.createRequest.requestId`:** `string`
>
> > The client-generated unique ID for this request.
> > Clients should regenerate this ID for every new request. If an ID provided is the same as for the previous request, the request is ignored.

With this information we can generate a Calendar Event creation request with a Meet link as the conference solution.

*My solution for the random string was to generate an **uuid**.*